# Change image search of surfaces in sceneform with arcore

Tags: arcore, android-augmented-reality, sceneform

where I change the sceneform_hand_phone.png image to a custom one?. This is the image of the hand that is used in the library sceneform for Android with ARCore.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**HelloSceneformActivity.java**:

```
public class HelloSceneformActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private View phoneImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ux);

        // Get AR fragment from layout
        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);

        // Disable plane discovery hand motion animation
        arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide();

        ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.sceneform_hand_layout);
        container.removeAllViews();

        // Create the new plane discovery animation and add it to the hand layout.
        phoneImage = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hand_layout, container, true);

        // Set the instructions view in the plane discovery controller.
        arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(phoneImage);
    }
}
```

**activity_ux.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sceneform_hand_layout"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context=".HelloSceneformActivity">

  <fragment class="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
      android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Put the custom hand animation in it's own layout file (it must be created dynamically), **hand_layout.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.HandMotionView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:foregroundGravity="center"
      android:scaleType="center"
      android:src="@drawable/YOURIMAGE" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
       classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Hello
I did what you indicate, the new image appears but the camera does not appear. Only the image with white background is seen.

Comment: @AtlasKeel sorry for delay, but ti show is not related with this code. I'm on another country now far away from my laptop, but you need to render the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the API endpoint you're looking for - 
https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/PlaneDiscoveryController#setInstructionView(android.view.View)

```java
class ExampleFragment : ArFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        val customDiscoveryView = <inflate custom view>
        planeDiscoveryController.setInstructionView(customDiscoveryView)
    }
}
```